# fbgetloginstatus: FB is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I am getting the common JS error "Uncaught Reference Error: FB is not defined "

There are a lot of questions on the same issue and I have tried each solution available on
stackoverflow but to no avail. Apparently, people seem to get this issue sometimes, I am getting it all the time. Can anyone spot an error ? I am not using a chnnel url file for the time being

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
 {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init=({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      //channelUrl : 'www.something.in/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : false, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
      }) ;

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
 } ;



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
   (function(d, debug){ 
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));



FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    alert(uid) ;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    alert("not authorised");
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    alert("NOTHING") ;
  }
 });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331165/fb-is-not-defined-problem

Comment: well Sahil, I tried all the solutions posted there. They don't work. One difference is that the user in the link above gets the error sometimes but my script as above has not worked as yet.

Comment: But I guess you have not followed them correctly. The calls are asynch, you call call additional code after FB.init() only. Call your FB.getLoginStatus function after FB.Init() (where // additional initialization code.. is written).

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the basic example to work?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/
(the full text under section 3)

I could get the basic simple example to load BUT when I included my own code base FB was never defined.
It turned out to be the fact that I had prototyped "Object" to have a method called 'copyProperties'.
I changed that method to 'copyProps' and it all works now.  So, if Facebook is prototyping Object for their own purposes then I'd guess there are some other potential collisions out there too.

Sure, this must be one reason everyone says not to prototype Object, but so convenient! Obviously, it's not enumerable, so don't yell at me too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried everything. I only solved it by requesting the Facebook script by jQuery and then initializing it:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxx', status: false, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    });
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert(uid) ;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
        alert("not authorised");
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        alert("NOTHING") ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a small mistake in  `FB.init=({`.

You have to remove equal sign after FB.init and your code look like:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  //channelUrl : 'www.something.in/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
  status     : false, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
  }) ;
```

One more mistake you have done . your div id is fb-root but at the time of initialize you declare facebook-jssdk id

just make sure both should be same

Comment: I made the change, this didn't help either :(  FB not defined prevails